# NextJS App Router how to logout on any 401 response

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js, fetch

I wrote a small wrapper for the NextJS fetch api to centralize all my requests and so far works as expected. Now I'd like to redirect to my `logout` url if I get a `401 status code`. By now, I'm doing something like this in my server components.-

```
data = await dataPromise

if (requestResult?.status == statusCode.forbidden) {
    redirect(`/${lang}/logout`)
}
```

which works but unfortunately I need to "manually" check status on every fetch requests (which by the way are not a lot, but still).

What I'm trying instead is to do that check inside my fetch wrapper, something like this.-

```
return fetch(getUrl(endpoint), {
    headers: fullHeaders,
  })
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.status == 401) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/logout'))
    }
    [...]
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data', error)
  })
```

but redirects aren't working as expected outside my server component context.

**Any idea on how to achieve this? Is it even possible?**

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @AbhishekAN unfotrunately not :( I was in kind of a rush and solved it manually from outside the fetch function. Any idea is welcomed though :)